# Paypal website too slow in iOS

Tags: ios, paypal, uiwebview

In my iphone app I am loading paypal site in a `UIWebView` in this way.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [mywebview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

But it is too slow when click on the pay button. Sometimes it move from the pay page, just keep appearing the loading icon. What is the reason for this. And I want to use the webview rather than use the paypal sdk.

Thanks

Comment: Your network could be slow it takes little time.

Comment: Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

> Your code is correct. It might be due to slow internet connection so
>   Test on wifi.you can put UIActivity indicator for showing progress to
>   user.

Comment: yeas Im testing it on wifi. And its still showing the site progress indicator but the problem is thats all, its keep rotating the indicator most of the time, so need to kill it and do again

Comment: I didnt check on iphone browser. But I checked in computer browser it works well